# Roblox Lua if statement still executing even when the value isn't true

Tags: lua, roblox

this has been a major problem in my game. I have been trying to make a script that will detect when a value is 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5. However, the if statements will still execute even if the value is 0, making the timer start before anyone can get into the elevator. This is really annoying, and I cannot fix it. Here is the script:

```lua
local players = workspace.TestMode.Players
players.Value = 0
wait(5)
script.Parent.Text = "Waiting for players..."

function StartTimer()
  while true do
    if players.Value == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then
      script.Parent.Text = "15"
      print("enough players")
      wait(0.1)
    else
      script.Parent.Text = "Waiting for players..."
      print("not enough players")
    end 
    if players.Value == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then
      wait(0.9)
      script.Parent.Text = "14"
    else
      script.Parent.Text = "Waiting for players..."
    end
    wait(0.1)
    if players.Value == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then
      wait(0.9)
      script.Parent.Text = "13"
    else
      script.Parent.Text = "Waiting for players..."
    end
    wait(0.1)
    if players.Value == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then
      wait(0.9)
      script.Parent.Text = "12"
    else
      script.Parent.Text = "Waiting for players..."
    end
    wait(0.1)
    if players.Value == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then
      wait(0.9)
      script.Parent.Text = "11"
    else
      script.Parent.Text = "Waiting for players..."
    end
    wait(0.1)
    if players.Value == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then
      wait(0.9)
      script.Parent.Text = "10"
    else
      script.Parent.Text = "Waiting for players..."
    end
    wait(0.1)
    if players.Value == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then
      wait(0.9)
      script.Parent.Text = "9"
    else
      script.Parent.Text = "Waiting for players..."
    end
    wait(0.1)
    if players.Value == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then
      wait(0.9)
      script.Parent.Text = "8"
    else
      script.Parent.Text = "Waiting for players..."
    end
    wait(0.1)
    if players.Value == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then
      wait(0.9)
      script.Parent.Text = "7"
    else
      script.Parent.Text = "Waiting for players..."
    end
    wait(0.1)
    if players.Value == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then
      wait(0.9)
      script.Parent.Text = "6"
    else
      script.Parent.Text = "Waiting for players..."
    end
    wait(0.1)
    if players.Value == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then
      wait(0.9)
      script.Parent.Text = "5"
    else
      script.Parent.Text = "Waiting for players..."
    end
    wait(0.1)
    if players.Value == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then
      wait(0.9)
      script.Parent.Text = "4"
    else
      script.Parent.Text = "Waiting for players..."
    end
    wait(0.1)
    if players.Value == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then
      wait(0.9)
      script.Parent.Text = "3"
    else
      script.Parent.Text = "Waiting for players..."
    end
    wait(0.1)
    if players.Value == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then
      wait(0.9)
      script.Parent.Text = "2"
    else
      script.Parent.Text = "Waiting for players..."
    end
    wait(0.1)
    if players.Value == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then
      wait(0.9)
      script.Parent.Text = "1"
    else
      script.Parent.Text = "Waiting for players..."
    end
    wait(0.1)
    if players.Value == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then
      wait(0.9)
      script.Parent.Text = "Teleporting players..."
    else
      script.Parent.Text = "Waiting for players..."
    end
  end
end
StartTimer()
```

Comment: You are using "or" incorrectly. It should be used like "if players.Value == 1 or players.Value ==2".  You should read some more documentation, there are better ways. You could also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510736/check-if-array-contains-specific-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Lua all values other then `nil` and `false` are `truthy` so when evaluated in a boolean context they will be treated as `true`.

```lua
if players.Value == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then
```

This means that your if condition is `players.Value == 1` `true` or is `2` `true` and so on. `2` is always `true`. so your if condition is always `true`.

your condition should look like:

```lua
if players.Value == 1 or players.Value == 2 or players.Value == 3 or players.Value == 4 or players.Value == 5 then
```

---

alternatively you could have a simpler condition here are some ideas:

```lua
if players.Value > 0 and players.Value <= 5 then
```

```lua
conditions = {[1] = true, [2] = true, [3] = true, [4] = true, [5] = true}

if conditions[players.Value] then
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer because the person above answered but this is just to tell you what was wrong with your script so you can learn from it. You did if players.Value == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5. When you use an if statment and then you have an or statement inside of it. You have to completely restart the code. For example it would have worked if it was if players.Value == 1 or players.Value == 2 or players.Value == 3, etc. That is why it wasn't working.