# Lua: Do I need to repeat variable in if?

Tags: lua

When I say
`if var == "one" or var == "two" or var == "three" or var == "four" then`
and the *var* is always the same, can I shorten this somehow, like
`if var == "one" or "two" or "three" or"four" then`

Do I have to use parenthesis?

Answer (score 5):

We can take advantage of tables. In particular, if `some_table` *doesn't* contain `some_key`, then `some_table[some_key]` returns `nil`, which is falsy.

For example:

```
if ({one=1, two=1, three=1, four=1})[var] then
```

I've used `1` because it's short to type, but you can use any value except `nil` or `false`, as those two are the only falsy values in Lua.

This creates a new table every time the condition is evaluated, so if you want to check it frequently (in a tight loop, for example), it may be worth it to create the table *outside* the loop:

```
local CONDITION = {one=1, two=1, three=1, four=1}
...
   -- inside a loop:
   if CONDITION[var] then
```

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. Unfortunately my upvote isn't counted yet due to my lack of reputation.

Answer (score 1):

The Lua's if statement expects a singular value. That value gets converted to boolean `true` and `false` values that determine the `if` behavior.

So, in other words, you can imagine your `if` like this:

```lua
condition = var == "one" or var == "two" or var == "three" or var == "four"
if condition then
    --...
end
```

So `if` doesn't help us with the repetition itself, but knowing what it expects, it's easy to create a helper function. We can make it take a value and a list of values, compare it to the values, and return true if there's any match. This is, incidentally, the same as checking if a list contains a specific element, [which is easier to search for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510736/check-if-array-contains-specific-value/33511182).

So, given such a simple helper:

```lua
function contains(t, x)
    for _, v in ipairs(t) do
        if v == x then
            return true
        end
    end

    return false
end
```

We can write your `if` like so:

```lua
if contains({"one", "two", "three", "four"}, var) then
    --...
end
```

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. Unfortunately my upvote isn't counted yet due to my lack of reputation.

Comment: The environment I'm working in even seems to have a 'contains' function somewhere in the lower modules.