# I have a set of keys in a table but I don't know how to check it

Tags: lua

This is what I got so far, It just prints out "incorrect code" with table.concat, but I get an error with table.find

```lua
local keys = {"KEY_!@#%$!@#$%^&*(AF^FJ#GSG#FSV#%345R#3553d",  "KEY_FJJN@UJFISFSFSF#&%W*CN#CUIWUUC#*W(*C$357275C"}

local key = "KEY_!@#%$!@#$%^&*(AF^FJ#GSG#FSV#%345R#3553d"

if key == table.find(keys) then
  print("Success")
else 
  print("Incorrect Key")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

[`table.concat`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.concat) is for joining an array-like table of strings and numbers into one string with optional string separator (default: `''`), and start and end indices.

```lua
table.concat { 'h', 3, 'l', 'l', 0 } -- creates the string `h3ll0`.
```

---

There is no `table.find` in Lua's Standard [Table Library](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.6). Does your implementation or environment provide one? If it does, I would expect the function would at least need to know what you are looking for. Something like

```lua
table.find(t, value)
```

because as is you are not passing any information about `key` to that function.

Otherwise, you will need to write your own function that searches a table for a given value.

See: [*Check if array contains specific value*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33511182/2505965).

---

[Lua 5.4 Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/)

Answer (score 2):

you do not have a set of keys in the [common programming sense of the word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)), and that is the solution to your question.

> a set is an abstract data type that can store unique values, without any particular order. It is a computer implementation of the mathematical concept of a finite set. **Unlike most other collection types, rather than retrieving a specific element from a set, one typically tests a value for membership in a set.**
> -Wikipedia

you can convert your `keys` table into a set, where you simply index the set with your `key` to find if the key is present in the set.

```lua
local keys = {"KEY_!@#%$!@#$%^&*(AF^FJ#GSG#FSV#%345R#3553d",  "KEY_FJJN@UJFISFSFSF#&%W*CN#CUIWUUC#*W(*C$357275C"}

local keyset = {}

for _, v in ipairs(keys) do
  keyset[v] = true
end

local key = "KEY_!@#%$!@#$%^&*(AF^FJ#GSG#FSV#%345R#3553d"

if keyset[key] then
  print("Success")
else 
  print("Incorrect Key")
end
```